# "Cannot declare String type without a maximum length"

Tags: vyper

I have a contract:

```py
interface IAggregatorV3:
    def description() -> String: view
```

But when I compile, I get:

```
Cannot declare String type without a maximum length
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In vyper, you have to declare the size of your strings. You can fix this by:

```py
interface IAggregatorV3:
    def description() -> String[1000]: view
```